# Patterns in indefinite integral (1)

Tags: polynomials, indefinite-integrals, pattern-recognition

So far, I've found out this:

$\int \arcsin x \mathrm d x = x \arcsin x + \sqrt{1-x^2}+C$
$\int x\arcsin x \mathrm d x = \dfrac{x^2}{2}\arcsin x +\dfrac {x}{4}\sqrt{1-x^2} -\dfrac{1}{4}\arcsin x + C$
$\int x^2 \arcsin x \mathrm d x = \dfrac {x^3}{3}\arcsin x+\dfrac{x^2}{9}\sqrt{1-x^2}+\dfrac{2}{9}\sqrt{1-x^2} + C$
$\int x^3 \arcsin x \mathrm d x = \dfrac{x^4}{4}\arcsin x+\dfrac{x^3}{4\times 4}\sqrt{1-x^2}+\dfrac{3x}{4\times 4\times 2}\sqrt{1-x^2}-\dfrac{3\times 1}{4\times 4\times 2}\arcsin x + C$
$\int x^4 \arcsin x \mathrm d x = \dfrac {x^5}{5}\arcsin x +\dfrac {x^4}{5 \times 5}\sqrt{1-x^2}+\dfrac{4x^2}{5\times 5\times 3}\sqrt{1-x^2} + \dfrac{4\times2}{5\times 5\times 3}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$
$\int x^5 \arcsin x \mathrm d x = 
\dfrac {x^6}{6}\arcsin x
+\dfrac {x^5}{6\times6}\sqrt{1-x^2}
+\dfrac{5x^3}{6\times6\times4}\sqrt{1-x^2}
+\dfrac{5\times3x}{6\times6\times4\times2}\sqrt{1-x^2}
-\dfrac{5\times3\times1}{6\times6\times4\times2}\arcsin x + C$

There seems to be a pattern. It seems like for any positive whole number $n$,
$\int x^n \arcsin x \mathrm d x = \mathrm{(polynomial)}\arcsin x + \mathrm{(polynomial)}\sqrt{1-x^2} + C$
So, what is the pattern? What should the above polynomial be?

Comment: By the way, am I allowed to register an account on Math Overflow?

Comment: You are (nothing's stopping you), but good luck asking there.

Comment: After a change of variable $x = \sin y$, this becomes $\int y\sin^n y \cos y dy$. You can think of integration by parts, perhaps with the intention of reducing to $\int y\sin^{n-2} y \cos y dy$ maybe.

Comment: If you apply integration by parts, you get: $\int \! x^n \mathrm{arcsin} (x) \, \mathrm d x = \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\mathrm{arcsin} (x) - \dfrac{1}{n+1}\int \! \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm d x$, which gives you the dependence on the arcsine. The $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ dependence requires more work, but this could be a starting point.

Comment: @TobyMak Good luck????

Comment: Related: $$\int ^{1}_{0} x^n \arcsin x \mathrm d x $$

Comment: Another related one: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int x^n \arcsin 
x \mathrm d x $$ $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^1_0 x^n \arcsin 
x \mathrm d x $$

Answer (score 2):

Note: please help with formatting
Here's what I found:

$\int x^n \arcsin x \mathrm d x$
$= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\arcsin x - \int \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm d x$
$= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\arcsin x - \dfrac{1}{n+1}\int \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm d x$
[ let x = sin u ]
$= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\arcsin x - \dfrac{1}{n+1}\int \dfrac{(\sin u)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{1-(\sin u)^2}}\mathrm d (\sin u)$
$= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\arcsin x - \dfrac{1}{n+1}\int (\sin u)^{n+1}\mathrm d u$
[ see integration chart ]
$= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\arcsin x - \dfrac{1}{n+1} \left( -\dfrac{1}{n+1}(\sin u)^n\cos u +\dfrac{n}{n+1}\int (\sin u)^{n-1}\mathrm d u \right)$
$= \cdots$
[ sin u = x ]
$= \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\arcsin x 
+ \dfrac{x^n}{(n+1)^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}
+ \dfrac{n  x^{n-2}}{(n+1)^2(n-1)}\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
+ \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}\cdot 
  \dfrac{(n-2)}{(n-1)}\cdot
  \dfrac{x^{n-4}}{(n-3)}\sqrt{1-x^2} + \cdots \\
+ \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}\cdot 
  \dfrac{(n-2)}{(n-1)}\cdot
  \dfrac{x^{n-4}}{(n-3)}\cdots
  \dfrac{5}{6}\cdot
  \dfrac{3}{4}\cdot
  \dfrac{x^1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}
- \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}\cdot 
  \dfrac{(n-2)}{(n-1)}\cdot
  \dfrac{x^{n-4}}{(n-3)}\cdots
  \dfrac{5}{6}\cdot
  \dfrac{3}{4}\cdot
  \dfrac{1}{2}\arcsin x + C$ [... when n is odd]

Or
$\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\arcsin x 
+ \dfrac{x^n}{(n+1)^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}
+ \dfrac{n  x^{n-2}}{(n+1)^2(n-1)}\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
+ \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}\cdot 
  \dfrac{(n-2)}{(n-1)}\cdot
  \dfrac{x^{n-4}}{(n-3)}\sqrt{1-x^2} + \cdots \\
+ \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}\cdot 
  \dfrac{(n-2)}{(n-1)}\cdot
  \dfrac{x^{n-4}}{(n-3)}\cdots
  \dfrac{4}{5}\cdot
  \dfrac{2}{3}\cdot
  \sqrt {1-x^2} + C$ [...when n is even]

Comment: This might explain the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5En*arcsin%20x) is what Wolfram alpha thinks about the solution of
$$\int x^n \arcsin (x) \;\text d x$$
Now, the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) is of course a polynomial. So, your guess for the pattern was quite right.

Now, Wolfram doesn't give you the steps. But, once you have the solution, it's very easy to prove that using induction. Note that in the induction step, you just need to do
$$\int x^{n+1} \arcsin (x) \;\text{d}x = \int x\cdot x^n \arcsin (x) \;\text
{d}x$$
and integrate by parts.

Scroll down the link I embedded to have the formula of differentiating the hypergeometric series. You will need it in the by parts method.

I hope, that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use Wikipedia.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Ok, use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html then :):):)